# How to get the DC gain out of this?

Tags: active-filter

[image: Filter]

The question is:

> In the filter circuit shown, R1 = 10kΩ, R2 = 10kΩ, R3 = 4kΩ, R4 = 6.8kΩ, C1 = 5.3nF, and C2 = 5.3nF. 1 nF = 1 nanofarad = 10-9 farads. What is the DC gain of this filter? Calculate your answer to at least the nearest tenth.

I tried many times but couldn't solve it. I tried how Sallen-Key low pass filter works and its formula.  There was some confusion in my concept, but eventually I solved it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: You need to show at least on of your attempts to solve it.  Explain how you tried to solve the task.  How did you start?  What assumptions can you make?  What things have you studied that might apply to this assignment?

Answer (score 1):

The DC gain is obtained by opening all the capacitors (cap impedance at 0 Hz is infinity).

Knowing that, the DC gain is simply that of a non-inverting amplifier:

$$
A_v = 1+\frac{R_4}{R_3}
$$

Comment: Genius ! You just have to KNOW how to interpret questions...